# Recover Bitlocker Drive using old windows installation

Tags: windows, windows-10, bitlocker

Anyone aware if it's possible to recover a Bitlocker drive considering the Bitlocker key is lost but having the Old Windows installation folder?

Scenario:
Windows 10 installation with 2 drives: C and D
Drive D is Encrypted with Bitlocker and the key is lost
The Windows 10 was upgraded in Drive C
Drive C had a working Windows 10 installation still present in Windows.OLD

Comment: If the old installation had no problem with Bitlocker, undo the installation and save your data, then try to decrypt the drive. Otherwise, enter BIOS and turn off the TPM and turn it back on, so it will prompt for the password instead of the 48 digit recovery key.  After log in using the password you can get the recovery key (and put it on file). If both recovery key and password are lost, boot a few times and hope it will recover automatically.

Comment: thanks a lot! The it support in my company eventually foind it in AD